# Filling C++ vector of strings with contents of two-dimensional character array: fail when size is too big

Tags: c++, rcpp

I am new to programming in  C++, and trying to write function that I want to run from R (using RCpp).

Within the function, I construct a C array of null-terminated character strings.

The function should return a std::vector, so I try to 'fill' the std::vector with the contents of the array of character strings.
This works (and gives the expected output) until the character string array exceeds a certain size (about half a million); any larger and the function crashes when run.  Why?

It seems that it isn't even necessary to 'fill' the entire std::vector - it's enough to just fill the first element to cause the crash.  However, if I fill the first element with a constant string (instead of from the character string array) this doesn't happen, and the function will happily create and return much larger std::vectors (for instance, 100 million strings).

Here is a minimal example (which I compile and run from R using Rcpp):

```
std::vector<std::string> test_function(int vecsize) {
    const char mystring[] = "will I crash or not?";
    char mychararray[ vecsize ][ sizeof(mystring) ];
    int i; for (i=0; i<sizeof(mystring); i++) {
        mychararray[0][i] = mystring[i];
    }
    std::vector<std::string> out_string(vecsize);
    out_string[0]=mychararray[0]; // this line causes crash when vecsize = 500000 or more
    // out_string[0]="like this I dont crash"; // but runs fine using this line instead with vecsize over 100 million
    return out_string;
}
```

Calling test_function(100000) is fine, but calling test_function(1000000) crashes.

I assume this is something trivial: thanks in advance for any advice or explanation what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Naturally, because you are allocating `mychararray` on the stack, and `1000000` chars could blow your stack up.

Comment: I was worried about using-up too much memory with `mychararray`, but naively assumed that this wasn't the problem since it doesn't cause any issue if I don't use it to fill the `out_string` vector (in other words: if I comment-out the `out_string[0]=mychararray[0];` line, it doesn't cause a crash, even though the `mychararray` array is still the same).  Could you explain what I'm missing?

Comment: A couple of things. 1. What does this have to do with `Rcpp`? 2. Why aren't you using a vector?

Comment: `char mychararray[ vecsize ]` is not allowed in Standard C++ . array sizes must be known at compile-time

Comment: @Joseph Wood - I marked this as Rcpp because I'm running in through Rcpp and, although I assume that it's a problem with the C++ content inside the function, I'm not 100% certain, I didn't want to exclude that the problem might have arisen from the way I'm trying to implement it.  I've only used C++ in this way (so far), so I'm not confident yet to isolate the problem by compiling/running in a completely different way.  But if this is considered wrong (or lazy) I could understand...

Comment: @Joseph Wood @Dirk - I did try using a vector (after I found that the example in the question crashed), by swapping the declaration `char mychararray[ vecsize ][ sizeof(mystring) ];` for `std::vector<std::string> mychararray( vecsize );`.  This prevents the crash using the minimal example above, but still crashes when I fill-up all the elements of the vector.  But I tried to keep the question as simple as possible, and I would still like to understand why the character array version in the example doesn't work.

Comment: @M.M - I did not know that: I assumed that 'if it compiles, it's syntactically Ok'.  Is this likely to be a hint to the problem, or does it just indicate that I'm unknowingly using a non-standard C++ compiler?

Comment: The latter. Also this is a semantic error, not a syntax one, and there are many other classes of semantic error that would compile OK but not be valid

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment by Joseph Wood.  You have the wrong mental model.

In R, a character variable is also different and a vector of those is different from numeric vectors.  But Rcpp still makes it easy to work with these.

A simple example of working with a matrix of character variables follows.

#### Code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::CharacterMatrix foo(Rcpp::CharacterMatrix x) {
  for (int i=0; i<x.rows(); i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<x.cols(); j++) {
      std::string s(x(i,j));
      s[0] = std::toupper(s[0]);
      x(i,j) = s;
    }
  }
  return x;
}

/*** R
foo(matrix(c("the","quick","brown","fox"),2,2))
*/
```

#### Output

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/61508511/answer.cpp")

R> foo(matrix(c("the","quick","brown","fox"),2,2))
     [,1]    [,2]   
[1,] "The"   "Brown"
[2,] "Quick" "Fox"  
R>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, and I think it's very likely that I have the wrong mental model!  But just to specify a couple of details about what I'm trying to do: the function is intended to return character strings that it 'builds' letter-by-letter from non-character arguments.  The length of all the character strings in the vector will all be the same as each other, and known from the arguments before the strings are built, so using a two-dimensional array seemed natural to me.

Comment: I guessed that it would be more efficient to 'build' character strings inside an empty two-dimensional array (if this will ever work without crashing...) than to 'grow' them inside a vector of empty strings, but can't test this until I have a version that doesn't crash when run with usefully-large input.

Comment: Build `std::string` for each element of the matrix. assign them, return. You have a lot of options for the `std::string`.  I would strongly advise NOT to think in terms of arrays of `char` amd explicit allocations (`new`, `free`; or `*alloc`, `delete`).